# How to use biber to convert integer to BibTeX-month macro

Tags: bibtex, conversion, biber

Is it possible with `biber` to convert

```
@misc{example,
  month = {04},
}
```

to

```
@misc{example,
  month = apr,
}
```

in which `apr` is a BibTeX macro?

I am aware of the mapping facilities, but the closest I can currently get, using

```
<map_step map_field_source="MONTH" map_match="04" map_replace="apr" />
```

is

```
@misc{example,
  month = {apr},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the option `--nostdmacros` on an earlier run to stop `biber` defining these macros internally in first place? If this doesn't work, I will address this in the `biber` dev version as this `biblatex` -> `bibtex` conversion is quite important.

There is a new option in 1.7 (currently in dev folder on SourceForge) called `--tool_macro_fields` which can be set to a csv list of fields to output without quoting (that is, their value is a `bibtex` macro). You will need `biblatex` 2.6. See the `biber` help output or the PDF manual.

So, in your case, you'll call `biber` like this:

```
biber --tool --tool_resolve --tool_macro_fields=month -g <conf> file.bib
```

Comment: I am unclear on what you mean exactly. I start from a bibliography in biblatex format, with `DATE`s actually, which I can straightforwardly convert to `YEAR` and `MONTH`, in the form of my initial example. So I never had the BibTeX format of my second example.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was wondering if you had ever had them in the macro form to begin with. I'll look into this shortly as an enhancement.

Comment: Updated answer with new option in 1.7

Comment: Using `--tool_macro_fields=MONTH` in the last (of three) `biber --tool` runs does what I want. Thanks! (N.B.: I used biber from the git dev branch, as provided by a Gentoo live ebuild.)